# Default value of execution_timeout in Python Operator in Airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I vaguely remember that the default value of execution_timeout is 15 minutes or 30 minutes but I couldn't find a relevant document anywhere. What is the default value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the documentation of the [Operators](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/index.html#baseoperator), the `execution_timeout` is set to `None` by default.

If you want to set any sort of upper limit then you'll have to explicitly specify it.

Answer (score 1):

`PythonOperator` inherits from `BaseOperator` so you should checkout `BaseOperator`'s document.

Answer (score 1):

The default task execution_timeout value for all the operators is None.

If not specified, then the value is considered as None, meaning that the operators are never timed out by default.